# A question about an exercise in Klaus Hulek book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

"Let $X, Y \subset \mathbb{C}^4$ be varieties defined by
$$
X := \{ (t,t^2,t^3,0) \,|\, t \in \mathbb{C} \}, \quad
Y := \{ (0, u, 0, 1) \,|\, u \in \mathbb{C} \}.
$$

The *join variety* of $X$ and $Y$ is the set
$$
J(X,Y) := \bigcup_{P\in X, Q\in Y} 
\overline{PQ} \subset \mathbb{C}^4,
$$

where $\overline{PQ}$ is the line through $P$ and $Q$.
Describe the set $J(X,Y)$.

Is $J(X,Y)$ an affine (or quasi-affine) variety?"

This is a problem in the chapter 1 of Klaus Hulek's algbraic geometry. I can somehow visualize what the join variety is in my head, but can't figure out at all if this is some variety.

Could anyone give me some answers?

Comment: Can you write down what an element of $J(X, Y)$ looks like, in terms of $t$, $u$, and some variable, say, $s$?